# Javascript: How to replace all "\" character to ""

Tags: javascript, regex, character-replacement

I try to replace "\" character to empty "" but I can't do it. How to solve it?

Here is my code

```
abc = abc.replace('\','');
```

Comment: What about marking the answer of @Tim as the right one if it does solve the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

to replace all occurrences in a string you need to use a regex with the `g` flag,

```
abc = abc.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

Comment: this is the correct answer according to question requirements

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to escape the backslash:

```
abc = abc.replace('\\', '');
```

If you want to replace all occurrences, you can try:

```
var pattern = '\\\\';
var re = new RegExp(pattern, 'g');
abc = abc.replace(re, '');
```

Comment: @AbdennourTOUMI I updated my answer to cover replace all.

Comment: If you are using `RegExp`, then you have to double escape the ``\``: `'\\\\'`. That's because `new RegExp('\\', 'g');` is equivalent to `/\/g` which is invalid. Currently your coed throws a SyntaxError.

Comment: @FelixKling Code is not spelled `coed`.  A `coed` typically throws sorority parties, not syntax errors :-)

Comment: @Tim: You don't say :P